# main faq page is not complete

Tags: support, status-completed

The [main faq page](https://movies.stackexchange.com/faq) is missing the "What kind of questions can I ask here?" section completly, and has wrong contents under "What kind of questions should I not ask here?" - copied from some programming site.

Is this being taken care of, before the site go live?

The quality standards here are pretty rough, so trying to add more text to satisfy them.
(Yes it worked, without above sentence I couldn't post this question)

Comment: Is this still an issue? If yes, are there any unclarities the existing answer don't already adress?

Comment: @NapoleonWilson lol, the whole faq has been removed since I posted this (which I totally forgot about :)) and replaced with Help Center... so no, not an issue any more, you can safely mark this as [meta-tag:status-completed] or norepro.

Answer (score 5):

Actually no it doesn't the community comes up with the FAQ so we are supposed to bring about the scope.

Do you see that banner at the top of this meta?

**Take ownership of your community - [Read The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)**

Yeah it's there for you to look at it and click.

The first two questions there are:

- Are questions about [subject] on or off topic?
- What should our FAQ contain?

Comment: Fair enough, but I can't see any way for ordinary members to edit the FAQ.

Comment: The normal action is for the community to ask those questions and it will be handled later on. @Shad

Comment: @Shadow Moderators can edit the FAQ. Until pro tems get appointed, that means us, the Community Team, will assist. Otherwise it'll then be on the pro tems we appoint, and moderators elected after that.